# Can an app in `/opt/extras` install themeable icons in `/usr/share`?

Tags: application-development, quickly

My application Variety Wallpaper Changer runs from `/opt/extras` and uses an indicator icon. I would like to make this indicator icon theme-specific. As far as I understand the standard way is to install named icons into `/usr/share/icons` with `xdg-icon-resource` at installation time. (Am I right about this?). I have two questions regarding this:

1. Variety installs and runs from `/opt/extras.ubuntu.com`. Is it acceptable for it to install icons in `/usr/share` using `xdg-icon-resource` or is there something else I can do to have theme-specific icons without special-casing themes and dynamically selecting the icon in the code?
2. Variety is packaged using Quickly (and I'm myself a newbie at packaging) - how can I configure it to install theme-specific named icons at installation time?

Answer (score 3):

Generally, the answer is no.  According to the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_2.3/fhs-2.3.pdf) (FHS), only files that are required to be in a certain location (like lock files and device files) are allowed to be outside of the `/opt` tree if your software is installed this way.

You are correct in that you can install icons to `/usr/share/icons`, but again, don't do it if your package installs to `/opt`.  I'm unfamiliar with Quickly, but consider changing your app so it installs to the "usual" places for Linux software:  `/usr/bin` for binaries, `/etc` for configuration files, `/usr/share` for data, etc.  That way, your icons won't be out of place!